# CMake: how to avoid escaping spaces in command line?

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, environment-variables, cflags

I'm trying to write a `CMakeLists.txt` file for a project with some `Makefile`-based dependencies. To build the dependencies I use  [ExternalProject CMake plugin](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html). In simple cases all is OK. But now I want to redefine `CFLAGS` variable for `Makefile`-based subproject and cannot do it.

I want to set the following:

```
CFLAGS='-fPIC -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon'
```

If I use this string literally in `BUILD_COMMAND` tag, the generated `Makefile` contains the following:

```
"CFLAGS='-fPIC" -mfloat-abi=softfp "-mfpu=neon'"
```

So I get this error during compilation:

> `/bin/sh: 1: CFLAGS='-fPIC: not found`

If I use `"CFLAGS='-fPIC -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon'"`, I get

```
"CFLAGS='-fPIC -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon'"
```

in generated `Makefile` and get this:

> `/bin/sh: 1: CFLAGS='-fPIC -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon': not found`

Is there a right way to quote string with whitespaces in CMake?

Comment: Use " but escape them inside the string with \". But you sould never change the CFLAGS this way, that removes user input and is not how to use CMake.

Comment: @usr1234567 It works, thank you! Can you post you advise as an answer to let me accept it? Redefining `CFLAGS` is surely a very bad idea, but for _external_ project with plain `Makefile` it seems the only way to manage compiler options.